# Finding the Radius & Segments of a Polygonal Circle to Match a Specific Face Size

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

bit of a weird question, but I am a 3D artist and I need to create a polygonal circle spline in which all the faces making up the circle have to be a specific size, but I am unsure of how to calculate this.

[Polygonal Circle With Radius of 1 & 2 Steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wg1D6.png)

The above image (linked) is an example of what I can create.
I have access to the radius and the step (face) amount, but I am trying to work out how to calculate the required step amount when using x radius and x size for each face.

If confused by the steps system, this shape is technically a subdivided square oriented diagonally, so the steps are the ADDITIONAL faces for each side (90 degrees diagonal).

Is there any easy way of doing this?
Thank you in advance for any help you can render.

Comment: By radius, are you referring to the distance from the center of each face to the center of the circle, or the distance from each point between two faces to the center?

Comment: If you know the length of each face (straight line along the rim of the circle), and you the distance from the center of the face to the center of the circle, then you should be able to use the inverted tan-function to find the number of degrees for each face. You then divide 360 by this number of degrees, and you should arrive at the number of faces.

Answer (score 1):

If we have the required length of face $l$ and radius $r$:

To determine the minimum number of faces of size $a \leq l$ use the formula (for $0<x\leq 2r $):
$$n=\left\lceil\frac{\pi}{\arcsin \frac{l}{2r}} \right\rceil$$

```
var n=Math.Ceiling(Math.Pi/Math.Asin(l/(2*r)));
```

Or maximum number of faces of size $a \geq l$:
$$n=\left\lfloor\frac{\pi}{\arcsin \frac{l}{2r}} \right\rfloor$$

```
var n=Math.Floor(Math.Pi/Math.Asin(l/(2*r)));
```

If we are given the radius $r$ and number of faces $n$, the length of each face is:
$$a=2r \sin \frac{\pi}{n}$$

```
var a = 2*r*Math.Sin(Math.Pi/n);
```

From the length of face $a$ and number of faces $n$ we can easily obtain the radius $r$
$$r=\frac{a}{2 \sin \frac{\pi}{n}}$$

```
var r = a/(2*Math.Sin(Math.Pi/n));
```

Having number of faces $n$ and radius $r$ you can generate the vertices of 'circle':
$$\begin{cases}x=r \cos { \frac{2k \pi}{n}}\\y=r \sin { \frac{2k \pi}{n}} \end{cases}$$
for $k=0,1,..., n-1$

```
var x=new double[n];
var y=new double[n];
for(var k=0; k<n; ++k)
{
   x[k]=r*Math.Cos(2*Math.Pi*k/n);
   y[k]=r*Math.Sin(2*Math.Pi*k/n);
}
```

Comment: In the first expression mentioned, what would a, x and n represent?
I am looking to build a small C# program to make this easier for me to use, but I am unsure of how to convert this into C# code and need to know what the variables are.

Comment: $x$ (replaced by $l$) - given length of face (it could be, that it does'nt fit the calculations and it have to be replaced by some other value $a$), $a$ - the actual size of face, $n$ - number of faces.

Comment: @K.Briggs I've posted some c# code examples